# Problema no build de produção ao usar CryptoJS

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-6

Tenho uma aplicação escrita em Angular 6 e surgiu uma necessidade de enviar um hash para o cliente. O contratante aprovou apenas o uso da biblioteca `crypto-js`. Fiz a implementação e tudo funciona corretamente no `ng serve`, porém ao fazer o build de produção ele dá um erro.

**Procedimento realizado:**

> Instalação da dependência do crypto-ts e dos typings.

```
npm install crypto-js --save
npm install @types/crypto-js --save-dev
```

**Uso do CryptoJS**

Eu faço o uso do `crypto-js` em um `service` do Angular. Deixo abaixo as duas maneiras que tentei usar a biblioteca para sanar o erro.

```
// Primeira maneira
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
console.log(CryptoJS.MD5('minha-string').toString());

// Segunda maneira
import { MD5 } from 'crypto-js';
console.log(MD5('minha-string').toString());
```

O erro retornado é `Module build failed`. Conforme abaixo:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/crypto-js/core.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
```

O problema só ocorre ao executar o comando `ng build --prod`

Alguém já passou por isso? Como poderia resolver o problema?

Obrigado.

Comment: vc adicionou a biblioteca no arquivo angular.json?

Comment: Então @EduardoVargas nos tutoriais não mencionou isso, poderia explicar como é feito?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts da uma olhada nesse link, tenta achar a propriedade scripts no seu angular.json ou angular-cli.json

Comment: @EduardoVargas tentei adicionar o endereço "./node_modules/crypto-js/core.js" no scripts do angular.json conforme descrito e ainda continuo a receber o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de sofrer um pouco eu consegui resolver meu problema, não acho que tenha sido a melhor maneira. Então caso alguém tenha uma outra solução para isso eu vou estar modificando a resposta correta.

O que eu fiz para resolver o problema:

Primeiro fui no arquivo `angular.json` e adicionei os scripts `core.js` e `md5.js` em meus scripts. Conforme abaixo:

```
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules/crypto-js/core.js",
    "./node_modules/crypto-js/md5.js"
]
```

> **Atenção:** Existem 2 lugares com a chave scripts, então modifique nos dois locais.

Após isso eu modifiquei meu service no angular conforme abaixo:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

declare var CryptoJS;
@Injectable()
export class HasherService {

     getMd5(str: string): string {
         return CryptoJS.MD5(str).toString();
     }

}
```